# Error when trying to acces website url during deployment Sympfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm deploying Symfony2 for the first time on a shared hosting.

I get different errors:

FIrst one when I try to acces the website by its normal url:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "C:/wamp/www/SocProNetbeans/app/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: fopen(C:/wamp/www/SocProNetbeans/app/logs/prod.log) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php:4987 Stack trace: #0 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4931): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array) #1 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(4856): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array) #2 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5056): Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler->handleBatch(Array) #3 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php(5361): Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array) #4 /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/cl in /home/stijnxk59/domains/stijnxk59.fiftynine.axc.nl/app/cache/prod/classes.php on line 4987
```

Second one is that I don't receive some background images in development mode

Comment: For your 2d error, have you run the asset:install command?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give **write** permissions for the two following folders :

- app/logs
- app/cache

Have a look at [symfony configuration and setup doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup).

Comment: Delete manually those folders and then retry to set up the permissions.

Comment: Omg, now I get Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "404 Not Found".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: I can acces the development mode just fine btw